# tf::Quaternion syntax question

Tags: quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Recently I've found out, that I *must* give the navigation stack a quaternion describing rotation in addition to the vector3D goal. Quaternions were new to me, so I learnt about them because I would like to use them in ROS. My question is about actual  implementation.

Suppose that I would like to go from (0,0,0) to (1,1,0). Then I know, that the robot would probably face to 45°, so...

double inRadian = radian(degree);

tf::Quaternion rotateByThis(tf::Vector3(0,0,1), inRadian); // is this call okay?

goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = ? // tf::Quaternion has getW() method, should I use that value?

goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.x = ?

goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.y = ?

goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.z = ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55923/tf::quaternion-syntax-question/) by [Peter Roos](https://answers.ros.org/users/2915/peter-roos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 119 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf provides some methods for the use case that you want to do (2D navigation).

In general there is:
[tf::createQuaternionFromYaw](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a9550bc7dce951899c5cb577f4d58b867)

Specifically for setting ROS messages, there is also:
[tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a09ddb5ff50f5032761feaa6a760f7344)

So, your code can be shortened to:

```
goal.target_pose.pose.orientation = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(inRadians)
```

You'll almost never have to set quaternion components manually when dealing with ROS data types. There are also conversions between tf types and messages for all common tf types.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza Ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1696/reza-ch/) on 2013-03-21**:
Hello, I have the question of other way round. How to get rotations of a quaternion to RPY? I mean in my code I use a /tf listener. So after lookupTransform, now I need to call the rotations and have themin  RPY. So how to call and convert them? Any wiki link is also appreciated.